# Middle-mouse-button (to move the screen) does not work anymore

Tags: versions

It seems my MMB is completely broken in Blender (only in Blender) because not even combinations with this button worked. It worked fine just a week ago, but since i have downloaded 2.76 this problem occurred, even when i switched back to 2.75. I don't know if the download of 2.76 was the impact because i didn't use Blender 2 days before i have updated it.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean what happens when you press and hold the MMB?

Comment: Ah yes, i mean that. I mistook it, sorry and thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your key binding has been changed.  Barring that I suggest a roll back of your machine to a known working date. Then try the install again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Photoshop Elements in parallel to Blender? I once ran into such a problem and it is a known issue of PE that the right mouse kind of redirected. For me, it helped to stop PE.